# Why can't I handle a limit exception in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, activerecord

Today I found a fantastic exception which I cannot handle.

When I write this code:

```
def example
  Integer('example show')
rescue 
  p 'All is good, I handle it'
end

> example
#=> 'All is good, I handle it'
```

But when `ActiveRecord` throws the exception, I get:

```
def example
  SomeModel.all.limit('example show')
rescue
  p 'All is bad, I cannot handle it'
end

> example
#=> ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "example show"
```

I thought it was some magical deep exception or nested exception, but this works fine too:

```
class A
  def a
    b
  end
  def b 
    Integer('show example')
  end
end

begin
  A.new.a
rescue
  p 'All is good, I can handle it'
end
=> 'All is good, I can handle it'
```

Comment: @DaveNewton, I updated my question, please take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because the evaluation of `SomeModel.all.limit` is delayed until outside your `rescue` block. `all.limit` returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` that doesn't actually run until it has to, so `example` returns just fine, and then later you try to use the value and Rails fails to convert `example show` to an `Integer`. Here's a demonstration from my console:

```
> def example
*   User.all.limit('something')
* rescue
*   puts 'Rescued'
* end
=> :example
> foo = example
=> #<#<Class:#<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_User:0x007ffb5b52e168>>:0x3ffdada970b4>
> foo.to_a
ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "something"
```

I'd recommend handling the conversion of `something` to an `Integer` yourself so you can catch this properly in your `example` method. Otherwise, you need to `rescue` whenever you access the return value of `example`, which isn't going to go well. You can also force instantiation of the relation inside `example` by calling `SomeModel.all.limit('something').load`. That will raise the exception where your `rescue` can catch it the way you expect.

Comment: Ah, you are right, I forgot that ActiveRecord::Relation wouldn't executed before rescue, so load will solve that trouble, thank you so much.

Comment: What is relevant here is not that it is delayed but that it perhaps runs in a different thread.

Comment: @sawa: I don't see any indication of threads in the example code, and can replicate this without concurrency. Where do you see those coming in?

Comment: @Kristján I don't know about this, but if it weren't running in a different thread, then it wouldn't finish the block while still running.